# 手元の HTML ファイルをブラウザでホスト名 localhost で閲覧する方法

Tags: html, http

index.htmlをlocalhostを使ってブラウザで見るにはどうしたらいいですか？

Comment: なぜ「普通にダブルクリックしてブラウザで開く」のがダメなのか、なぜ「localhostを使って」と言う指定が入っているのかが全然わかりません。それらの改善がないままで再オープンの提案がなされると言うのも全くわかりません。

Comment: なるほど。質問者が「なぜ」これを必要としているか、が必要だという事ですね。
そういう事のようですので、質問者さんはぜひ補足をして下さい。
また、こういった事は「改善待ち」にする際に指摘されるべき事だと思います。
（私は「なぜ」かわからなくとも回答可能な質問だと思いましたし、だいたい想像が付く事でもあるので再オープンに投票しています）

Comment: @mjy さん、「こういった事は「改善待ち」にする際に指摘されるべき事だと思います。」については、大いに賛成ですし、私のコメントもそれを具体的に表現させていただいたつもりです。が、これ以上はメタネタですね。

Comment: 関連?: ["What is a faster alternative to Python's http.server (or SimpleHTTPServer)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12905426/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: 参考: ["開発用ローカルサーバを立ち上げる方法"](http://qiita.com/higuma/items/b23ca9d96dac49999ab9) -- Qiita

Comment: 質問には目的を書かなければならないかについて、metaにポストしました https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2548

Answer (score 1):

開発用のローカルサーバを立てるにはpythonで行うのが早いです。
python2ではSimpleHTTPServerを使います。

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

python3ではhttp.serverを使います。

```
$ python3 -m http.server
```

ポート番号を省略すると8000が用いられますので、ブラウザから http://localhost:8000 (または単にlocalhost:8000) にアクセスすれば起動したディレクトリをルートとしてサーバが起動します。

Comment: $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
で解決することができました。ありがとうございます。